# Engine/Car Shaking in 3rd, 4th and 5th. Help!

Tags: engine, transmission, audi, shaking

So I've encountered an issue with my car today which I can't put my finger on, and wanted to get some consumer advice before taking it to a mechanic!

It's a **2011 AUDI A1 1.2 TFSI**. I've had it for about 2 years with no issues, <70k on the clock.

I drove to work this morning fine no issues, however when I left work, I drove about 50 yards before the whole car shook fairly violently. I pulled over, got out and checked the wheels, of which there are no issues, and re-started the car to find the problem persisting. I rolled my car back home, and after doing some thinking and looking there are no visual issues with the car.

I've established that **my car shakes under the following circumstances:**

- When idling in neutral
- When being used at any RPM in 3rd, 4th or 5th
- When accelerating too hard in 2nd.

And to add some contradiction, I experience **NO issues** when above 1500rpm in neutral, 1st and 2nd.

The feeling off the car shaking is very similar to the way it feels when you accidentally put your car in 4th rather than second, and you're going too slow, so the car shudders (I think this is called engine lugging?). As I mentioned this **only happens in 3rd, 4th and 5th** and this is **regardless off the rpm/speed.** As a result of the above I can't tell whether this is an e**ngine fault or transmission fault**, as it seems both the **RPM and the selected gear effects the car shaking**!! I had the gearbox reconditioned about a year ago, so I'm hoping that's not the problem!! This is backed up by the fact the engine light occasionally flashed since this problem has arisen, but not always....

The cars is fairly good nick, I've had it recently fully serviced at Audi. I've checked all fluid levels and they appear fine (excluding transmission fluid because I can't find it...)  I've not experienced this issue before or anything similar, and there's nothing else out of the ordinary as far as I'm concerned. The only other thing I can possibly think might even have the slightest effect is that I recently had the car quite thoroughly washed.

Hopefully there's someone out there who can shed some light so that my mechanic doesn't con me out of thousands of pounds when I go to get it fixed!!

Thanks in advance!

SS

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!